# Django's dumpdata only dumping auth permission and contenttypes data

Tags: python, django, postgresql, loaddata, dumpdata

I use local Postgres on the dev environment and deployed my app to Heroku with Postgres as well.
I migrated my database, and now I want to load my data.
The app works fine on Heroku, but without data.

I have different settings files for dev and prod - with local Postgres and Postgres on Heroku correspondingly.

I have my data on dev Postgres, and when I launch the app on dev - I see the data.
To dump data I set my dev settings where dev database settings are:

```
./manage.py dumpdata --indent=4 --settings=app.settings.dev > data3.json
```

I see that only data from auth.permission and contenttypes.contenttype are there:

> [{"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "Can add log
> entry", "content_type": 1, "codename": "add_logentry"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 2, "fields": {"name": "Can change log entry",
> "content_type": 1, "codename": "change_logentry"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 3, "fields": {"name": "Can delete log entry",
> "content_type": 1, "codename": "delete_logentry"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 4, "fields": {"name": "Can view log entry",
> "content_type": 1, "codename": "view_logentry"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 5, "fields": {"name": "Can add permission",
> "content_type": 2, "codename": "add_permission"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 6, "fields": {"name": "Can change
> permission", "content_type": 2, "codename": "change_permission"}},
> {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 7, "fields": {"name": "Can delete
> permission", "content_type": 2, "codename": "delete_permission"}},
> {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 8, "fields": {"name": "Can view
> permission", "content_type": 2, "codename": "view_permission"}},
> {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 9, "fields": {"name": "Can add
> group", "content_type": 3, "codename": "add_group"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 10, "fields": {"name": "Can change group",
> "content_type": 3, "codename": "change_group"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 11, "fields": {"name": "Can delete group",
> "content_type": 3, "codename": "delete_group"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 12, "fields": {"name": "Can view group",
> "content_type": 3, "codename": "view_group"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 13, "fields": {"name": "Can add content
> type", "content_type": 4, "codename": "add_contenttype"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 14, "fields": {"name": "Can change content
> type", "content_type": 4, "codename": "change_contenttype"}},
> {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 15, "fields": {"name": "Can delete
> content type", "content_type": 4, "codename": "delete_contenttype"}},
> {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 16, "fields": {"name": "Can view
> content type", "content_type": 4, "codename": "view_contenttype"}},
> {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 17, "fields": {"name": "Can add
> session", "content_type": 5, "codename": "add_session"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 18, "fields": {"name": "Can change session",
> "content_type": 5, "codename": "change_session"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 19, "fields": {"name": "Can delete session",
> "content_type": 5, "codename": "delete_session"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 20, "fields": {"name": "Can view session",
> "content_type": 5, "codename": "view_session"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 21, "fields": {"name": "Can add user",
> "content_type": 6, "codename": "add_useraccount"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 22, "fields": {"name": "Can change user",
> "content_type": 6, "codename": "change_useraccount"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 23, "fields": {"name": "Can delete user",
> "content_type": 6, "codename": "delete_useraccount"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 24, "fields": {"name": "Can view user",
> "content_type": 6, "codename": "view_useraccount"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 25, "fields": {"name": "Can add fund",
> "content_type": 7, "codename": "add_fund"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 26, "fields": {"name": "Can change fund",
> "content_type": 7, "codename": "change_fund"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 27, "fields": {"name": "Can delete fund",
> "content_type": 7, "codename": "delete_fund"}}, {"model":
> "auth.permission", "pk": 28, "fields": {"name": "Can view fund",
> "content_type": 7, "codename": "view_fund"}}, {"model":
> "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 1, "fields": {"app_label": "admin",
> "model": "logentry"}}, {"model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 2,
> "fields": {"app_label": "auth", "model": "permission"}}, {"model":
> "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 3, "fields": {"app_label": "auth",
> "model": "group"}}, {"model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 4,
> "fields": {"app_label": "contenttypes", "model": "contenttype"}},
> {"model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 5, "fields": {"app_label":
> "sessions", "model": "session"}}, {"model":
> "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 6, "fields": {"app_label":
> "user_account", "model": "useraccount"}}, {"model":
> "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 7, "fields": {"app_label": "fund",
> "model": "fund"}}]

So when I `loaddata` to Heroku - there is no data on prod.
I tried to explicitly set the apps from which I need data, but in this case, I receive an empty list:

```
./manage.py dumpdata fund user_account --settings=app.settings.dev > data3.json
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can try this command:

```
heroku run python manage.py dumpdata --natural -- > data.json
```